# Which wireless triggers are recommended for Bowens Gemin 200/200?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon, studio-lighting

The title says all.

I am new to studio light photography and I am looking for a wireless trigger I can use with these `monolights`.

Can you make any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would depend on whether you have the newer "Rx" model flashes (in which case you'd just need Bowens' Pulsar TX transmitter, since the receiver is built into the flashes) or the older standard Gemini 200s. If you have the older ones, then any decent radio trigger (preferably one that has a PC or miniplug terminal) will do the trick. Among the suitable candidates are the well-regarded, low-cost Cactus V5 and Yongnuo RF-602/603 transceivers, as well as the somewhat costlier PocketWizard Plus X (and the Plus II/Plus III at what might seem to be frighteningly more money). Phottix also makes a low-cost unit that has good reviews, but I have no direct experience with it.

Comment: Yep... Pretty much anything that you can plug onto the sync port. I've used Cactus IV on my AB800s, though I do find they have lag so it can be a bit hit or miss on max sync speed. I get the odd black bar, especially when using hot shoe flashes.